# FB fanpage custom layouts

Tags: ssl-certificate, facebook-iframe

On my FBpage I wish to add custom tabs, within these tabs/iframes I want to external link my website (html/css, hosted on One.com, no SSL) so to achieve a fancy design, kind of like these:

http://bit.ly/YX1Vpr
http://on.fb.me/14NITT5

Tried the app "Static HTML" and added three tabs (Info, Contact, Biography) and I found two interesting options:

1) "Static HTML
A simple HTML editor allowing you to create static HTML content"

2) "Website
Use a page from your website. Includes resizing functionality."

Tried option 2 and linked an external page hosted on One.com, but it doesn’t seem to work on tablets/phones.

BOTTOM QUESTION: Any way to get around the SSLrestriction, ie by apps such as Static HTML, Woobox etc - or do I just need an SSL either way?

Comment: If you have had an answer, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a custom layout on Facebook pages OR profiles. You can add custom tabs via adding applications to your facebook page. **Below are a few good pre packaged Facebook application providers**. The list is ordered by perceived quality vs price (some are free, some are paid, and some allow you to white label your application after paying X dollars per month). Note that this ordering is completely subjective to my experience.

```
http://www.wildfireapp.com/plans (specific for promotions)
http://www.votigo.com/corp/features-and-pricing.php (specific for promotions)
http://www.shortstackapp.com/ (white label $30 and up)
https://www.socialappshq.com/home/pricing (white label $99 and up)
http://northsocial.com/pricing/ (SRM, white label $79 and up, also pricey)
http://www.agorapulse.com/pricing/ (white label $145 and up)
http://www.pagemodo.com/pricing (white label $30 and up)
http://thrusocial.com/index/subscribe (white label $20 and up)
http://www.tabfusion.com/pricing.php
http://www.faceitpages.com/pricing.php (white label $125 and up)
http://www.tabsite.com/pricing.php
```

Besides the above, you CAN develop Facebook applications and host them on your OWN server. This is a much more complicated setup, and I recommend you start with one of the options above. **If you decide to use this method you will need to purchase an SSL certificate for the domain under which you are hosting your FB app, EVEN if your app is only static content**. Find a [suitable SSL sert provider via a simple search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en-US&pws=0&q=ssl%20cert).

Comment: I dont think I was clear enough, apologizes. 

What I'm wanting to do is the custom tabs, and within these tabs I want to iframe-link my website which I coded using html and css (it' hosted on One.com, which does not offer ssl).
Just like these pages:

http://mxcdn.incomediary.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Gary-Vaynerchuk-Facebook-Page.png
https://www.facebook.com/McDonalds/app_288569311195996

Comment: Tried "Static HTML" to add tabs & I found 2interesting options:

1 "Static HTML. A simple HTML editor allowing you to create static HTML content"

2 "Website. Use a page from your website. Includes resizing functionality."

Tried no2, linked an external page hosted @ One, but it doesnt work on tablets/phones. 

QUESTION IS, is there any way to get around the ssl restriction, ie using apps such as Static HTML and Woobox - OR do I just need an SSL either way?

Comment: SO what you are trying to do is option #2, the one that is more complicated UNLESS you actually want only static content, which is your case ;). Bottom line. YES you will need to purchase an SSL cert for an SSL certificate for the domain under which you are hosting your FB app (in this case static content). I am editing the answer to make it more clear.